# "Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance" error in iOS native code

Tags: codenameone

I'm getting an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error message on my iPhone that I can't figure out. I'm running the native iOS source from XCode, and I get stuck during initialization with this error message when I call the setInterval() method.

The method is simple. I'm using the sensors, so I have this interface

```
public interface SensorsNative extends NativeInterface {
  ...
  void setInterval(int type, int delayMicroSeconds);
}
```

My ios native implementation looks like this:

```
-(void)setInterval:(int)type delay:(int)delayMicroSeconds {
  // accelerometerUpdateInterval is in seconds.
  NSTimeInterval delaySeconds = delayMicroSeconds / 1000000.0;

  if (type == GYRO) {
    [motionManager setGyroUpdateInterval: delaySeconds];
  } else if (type == ACCEL) {
    [motionManager setAccelerometerUpdateInterval:delaySeconds];
  } else if (type == MAGNET) {
    [motionManager setMagnetometerUpdateInterval: delaySeconds];
  }
}
```

My SensorsNative instance is static, so it can't get garbage collected, and I can see from the attached Xcode output that my parameters have the right values, and ptr, my pointer, is of the right type. I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you changed the name of your native implementation iOS method.  It should be `setInterval:param1:`, but you changed it to `setInterval:delay:`

e.g.

```
-(void)setInterval:(int)type param1:(int)delayMicroSeconds {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.